# Do any functions in the R language besides "formula" parse functions form string Vectors?

Tags: r, security, vector

Due to the fact that "formula" takes a character vector with R functions included, it creates a security concern as explained in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1303.4808.pdf.

Situations like this can occur:

```
userformula <- "speed ~ dist + system('whoami')"
lm(userformula, data=cars)
```

While I have sensibly audited any functions in my application which take "formula" as a parameter, I am curious:

1) Do any other R functions besides formulas allow for R functions to be included as character vectors as Formula does? Which other functions should I watch out for with the same issue?

2) Is it possible to force a function to take a formula as a param? If so, how can I prevent this?

Edit: I am restricting this to the base R packages.

Comment: Can you restrict this to `base` R and the default packages? Otherwise it seems the scope is too big... at least `ggplot2::aes_string`, `dplyr::mutate_` and most all of the Tidyverse's standard-evaluating function versions. And who knows about the other thousands of packages on CRAN and elsewhere.

Comment: Sure! I'll edit it.

Comment: If you know that `fo` is a formula, e.g. `fo <- formula(userformula)` where `userformula` is the string in the question, then `setdiff(all.names(fo), all.vars(fo))` will list all the functions in it and you can reject any formula whose functions are not all on a white list of your choosing.

Comment: I'm less interested in the whitelisting aspect, than how identifying similar vulnerable functions.